# sum column not working properly with sub query

Tags: mysql

i have some code to mysql query, but it's not showing right result.

This is my code:

```
select a.spent
     , t_rinci.harga as price 
  from t_pengajuan 
  join t_rinci 
    on t_rinci.id_pengajuan = t_pengajuan.id 
  left 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT t_realisasi.id_rinci as id
            , SUM(nilai_realisasi) spent 
         FROM t_realisasi 
        GROUP
            by id ) a 
    on a.id = t_rinci.id_rinci 
 where t_rinci.id_rinci in (a.id) 
 group 
    by t_rinci.id_pengajuan
```

expected result is

| spent | price |
| --- | --- |
| 400000 | 4250000 |
| 1000000 | 1100000 |

but it say

| spent | price |
| --- | --- |
| 400000 | 4250000 |
| 1000000 | 1000000 |

[here my sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f7595/23)

Comment: 'but it say' is correct..BTW you don't need the last group by.

Comment: no, if you see my fiddle run this query  select * from t_rinci, it will show you in column id_pengajuan has 2 records, it have harga with 100000 and 1000000, it should be 1100000, not 1000000

Comment: Your final WHERE clause and GROUP BY are both misleading. Remove them. Or change SELECT to SUM (t_rinci.harga) - but still remove the WHERE CLAUSE, and change LEFT JOIN To INNER JOIN

Comment: then how should it be?

Comment: if i have records in t_rinci, and its not have records in t_realisasi,
I still need that data to show 
for example :

spent -> price
0 ->10000 
 that the reason i use left join

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a coherent query:

```
select r.id_pengajuan
     , SUM(a.spent) spent
     , SUM(r.harga) as price 
  from t_pengajuan p
  join t_rinci r
    on r.id_pengajuan = p.id  
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT t_realisasi.id_rinci as id
            , SUM(nilai_realisasi) spent 
         FROM t_realisasi 
        GROUP
            by id ) a 
    on a.id = r.id_rinci  
 group 
    by r.id_pengajuan
```

It might not be what you're after, but it does at least make sense.

Comment: the price should be 1100000 not 1000000